# using squeeze theorem to prove differentiability

Tags: limits, derivatives

I have this inequality
\begin{align}
2x\leq f(x)\leq x^2 + 1
\end{align}
and have to compute $\lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ to show that f(x) is differentiable at x = 1. I understand that I can use the squeeze theorem to show that $\lim_{x\to 1}$ f(x) is = 2. I have tried using the mean value theorem as well but I am stumped on how to tackle the left limit in particular and if I should be using the mean value theorem in the first place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you have $a\le b\le c$ which gave you $f(1)=2$. Then $a-2\le b-2\le c-2$ and then...

Comment: May I know if that assumes that f(x) is defined at x=1? Also may I know about the significance of the left limit rather than just limit?

Comment: Well, if the inequality given holds for all $x$, just put $x=1$: no squeeze needed. For the 2nd Q. Think about what happens when $x-1$ has  a sign

Comment: Thank you for your help I will work towards that.

Comment: actually, now that I read it again, I don't understand why you only have $\lim_{x\to 1^-}$...I think both sides should be true

Comment: it is based on the question set that I have

Answer (score 1):

$$2x\leq f(x) \leq x^2+1$$

$f(1)$ in limit allows to suppose that $f(1)$ exists, otherwise we cannot take the limit

If $f(1)$ exists then $2\leq f(1) \leq 2 \Rightarrow f(1)=2$

Then limit transforms to $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}$$

$$x>1 : \frac{2x-2}{x-1} \leq \frac{f(x)-2}{x-1} \leq \frac{x^2+1-2}{x-1} \Rightarrow 2 \leq \frac{f(x)-2}{x-1} \leq x+1$$
$$x<1 : \frac{2x-2}{x-1} \geq \frac{f(x)-2}{x-1} \geq \frac{x^2+1-2}{x-1} \Rightarrow 2 \geq \frac{f(x)-2}{x-1} \geq x+1$$

In both cases $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)-2}{x-1} = 2$, as $\lim_{x\to 1} x+1 = 2$, $\lim_{x\to 1} 2 = 2$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!